# Error while installing Windows Phone SDK

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, installation

while i am installing windows phone 7 SDK following error is occured and setup can not complete.

[image: errow when installing Windows Phone SDK 7.1]

Any one know how to resolve this error and install Windows Phone 7 SDK.

i already installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate but still installation error is coming

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But have you installed SP1?  If not, go ahead and install this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691